# Dynamically add/remove Finish from QWizardPage based on change in its content

Tags: qt, pyqt, wizard, transition, pyqt5

I'm following the tutorial on a [license wizard](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-licensewizard-example.html) (using `PyQt5`) trying to learn how to create non-linear wizards. However I seem to be stuck on an issue.

I want to have a page with a `QComboBox` where the selected item determines whether the current `QWizardPage` that contains the combobox is the final page or not.

Here is what the page contains so far:

```
class CalibrationPageSource(QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(CalibrationPageSource, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setTitle('Calibration Wizard')
        self.setSubTitle('Select the source for the calibration')

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        label = QLabel('''
            <ul>
                <li><b>From calibration file</b>: browse and select an existing YAML calibration file that contains the camera matrix and distortion coefficients (for example from a previous calibration)</li>
                <li><b>From image files</b>: browse and select one or more image files with the calibration pattern visible inside each</li>
                <li><b>From stream</b> - if the calibration node is connected to an active <b><i>Device node</i></b> you can use its image stream to interactively calibrate your device</li>
            </ul>
        ''')
        label.setWordWrap(True)
        layout.addWidget(label)

        layout_sources = QHBoxLayout()
        label_sources = QLabel('Source:')
        self.selection_sources = QComboBox()
        self.selection_sources.addItem('Calibration file')
        self.selection_sources.addItem('Image files')
        self.selection_sources.addItem('Stream')
        self.selection_sources.currentIndexChanged['QString'].connect(self.source_changed)
        self.selection_sources.setCurrentIndex(1)
        layout_sources.addWidget(label_sources)
        layout_sources.addWidget(self.selection_sources)
        layout.addLayout(layout_sources)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def source_changed(self, source):
        if source == 'Calibration file':
            self.setFinalPage(True)
            # TODO Add file dialog
        else:
            self.setFinalPage(False)
            # TODO Remove file dialog (if present)
```

Whenever `self.selection_sources`'s current item changes to `Calibration file` I would like to skip the rest of the wizard that is make the page final. In this case I want to remove the `Next` button. In all other cases (currently only two: `Image files` and `Stream`) I want to have the wizard act normally that is not as a final page.

I have tried implementing a custom `isComplete(...)` but the problem is that it disables both `Next` and `Finish` when `Calibration file` is selected. I can live with having a disabled `Next` button (instead of completely hiding it) but a disabled `Finish` basically doesn't make sense in my case. I'm actually surprised that the `Next` button is present. Isn't it supposed to go away completely when a final page has been reached?

Any ideas how to solve this problem? I thought about iterating through the items in the `QWizardPage` and manually disabling/hiding the `Next` button but I hope that there is an easier, out-of-the-box way to do that. In the current state the dynamic insertion of `Finish` is working however due to the `Next` button the wizard's transitions are not properly set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you use already `QWizardPage.setFinalPage(True)` to add a finish button to an intermediate page. Now the next button still exists. One way to remove it (not sure if this is the best way) is removing all following pages by calling `QWizard.removePage()` in conjunction with `QWizard.nextId()`.

Example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def end_wizard_after_page_two():
    # add finish button to wizard
    p2.setFinalPage(True)
    # remove all over buttons
    while True:
        id = w.nextId()
        if id == -1:
            break
        w.removePage(id)

app = QApplication([])

# page 1
p1 = QWizardPage()
p1.setTitle('Page 1')

# page 2
p2 = QWizardPage()
p2.setTitle('Page 2')

b = QPushButton('No further pages')
b.clicked.connect(end_wizard_after_page_two)
l = QVBoxLayout(p2)
l.addWidget(b)

# page 3
p3 = QWizardPage()
p3.setTitle('Page 3')

# wizard
w = QWizard()
w.addPage(p1)
w.addPage(p2)
w.addPage(p3)
w.show()

app.exec_()
```

See method `end_wizard_after_page_two()` in this example.

If you want to reverse the effect you would have to do everything in reverse (adding the remaining pages again and setFinalPage to False).

Comment: Nice. It works. I have to wonder though if there isn't a more efficient way of doing this. For now I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This is almost a year late, but I think I figured out what the problem is.  Your call to `setFinalPage(True)`, just sets a state flag in your `QWizardPage`. It does not automatically propagate back to your `QWizard`.

There is only one signal that does propagate information back: [`completeChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizardpage.html#completeChanged). The name is slightly misleading, but the docs seem to indicate that it does what you want if you read them just right:

> If you reimplement `isComplete()`, make sure to emit `completeChanged()` whenever the value of `isComplete()` changes, to ensure that `QWizard` updates the enabled or disabled state of its buttons.

In fact, having run into the same problem, I was able to fix it by doing

```
if source == 'Calibration file':
    self.setFinalPage(True)
    ...
else:
    self.setFinalPage(False)
    ...
self.completeChanged.emit()
```

The bolded line is new. It needs to be called in both cases and will toggle the button from "Next" to "Finish" and back as you select different options.

Comment: I ended up having to emit `completeChanged()` for dynamically changing the `QWizardPage::nextId()` value as well.