# How can I unregister fields in python Qwizard?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwizard

I have an app using PyQt5 and Qwizard (I can't post the real app because I'm not allowed to) and this is the structure.

I would like that the line edit in page 1 is a mandatory field unless the checkbox is checked.

I tried registering the line edit field, but when I check the checkbox it doesn't let me proceed.

I thought about doing something like if checked then register, but I cant find how to unregister the line edit field.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QToolBar, QAction, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QLabel,\
    QGroupBox, QWizard, QWizardPage, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QComboBox
import PyQt5.QtGui as QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.left = 200
        self.top = 200
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.title = "App"
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("logo.ico"))
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.toolbar = QToolBar("")

        ########################## ToolbarButtons ###################################
        self.button_add = QAction("Add", self)
        self.button_add.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("add.ico"))
        self.button_add.setStatusTip("Add stuff")
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.button_add)
        self.button_browse = QAction("Open", self)
        self.button_browse.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("folder.ico"))
        self.button_browse.setStatusTip("Open stuff")
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.button_browse)
        self.button_save = QAction("Save", self)
        self.button_save.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("save.ico"))
        self.button_save.setStatusTip("Save stuff")
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.button_save)
        self.button_settings = QAction("Settings", self)
        self.button_settings.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("settings.ico"))
        self.button_settings.setStatusTip("Set stuff")
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.button_settings)


        self.window_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.window_layout)
        self.wizard = WizardInit()
        print("Test")
        self.wizard.setWizardStyle(QWizard.ModernStyle)
        self.show()
        self.wizard.show()


class WizardInit(QWizard):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Wizard")
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.addPage(Page1())


class Page1(QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.registerField("Test*", self.line_edit)
        self.check_box = QCheckBox("test_checkbox")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to unregister the fields.

A possible solution is to override the isComplete method that determines whether the "Next" or "Finish" button are enabled or not, and to update it, the completeChanged signal must be emitted.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Wizard(QtWidgets.QWizard):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Wizard")
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.addPage(Page1())


class Page1(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.check_box = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("test_checkbox")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        lay.addWidget(self.check_box)

        self.registerField("Test*", self.line_edit)
        self.check_box.toggled.connect(self.completeChanged)

    def isComplete(self):
        if self.check_box.isChecked():
            return True
        return super().isComplete()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Wizard()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: this works ! 

Another question if i may... the isComplete will override any other fields i have in there.
if i had more then 1 label and more then 1 check box and even other different widgets , i would need to write the whole isComplete logic for this page my self?

and there is no need to registerField in that case?

Comment: @Udi isComplete is a method that enables the "Next" and "Finish" buttons that uses the mandatory fields by default but you can write your own logic, in my solution I just wanted to modify the behavior for the checkbox but if your page is more complex then you will have than implement your own logic. Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60608315/6622587